# Angular Json Http Get - Not load

Tags: angularjs, json

This is a simple test to fetch json file from third party server, but no success. I did test with this json (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) and is working. Any body can help me? Thanks in advance.

```js
var app = angular.module("viewJSON",[]);
app.controller("viewCtrl",function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://media.astropublications.com.my/api/drebar_landing.json').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.testJer = data;
     $scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.testJer[0]);
        });
});
```

```css
section {height:180px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



  <div ng-app="viewJSON" ng-controller="viewCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="item in testJer | filter:search">
    <section class="col-md-3">
        <h4>{{item.Title}}</h4>
        <p>{{item.Description}}</p>
    </section>
 </div>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the **`ArticleObject`** array from the response ,

```
app.controller("viewCtrl", function Hello($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://media.astropublications.com.my/api/drebar_landing.json').
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.testJer = data.ArticleObject;
  });
});
```

**[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/0yIufkwqXsjXivW5tzTM?p=preview)**